# every ultrafilter on $X$ has exactly one limit

Tags: general-topology, filters

**A topological space $X$ is Hausdorff compact iff every ultrafilter on $X$ has exactly one limit.**

> I know thatA topological space $X$ is Hausdorff compact if every ultrafilter on $X$ has exactly one limit.
>
> I know that every ultrafilter on $X$ has exactly one limit
>    is compact.
>
> But, I dont know
>
> **Why does " every ultrafilter on $X$ has exactly one limit
>    is Hausdoff** "?

Comment: A space $X$ is compact iff every ultrafilter on $X$ converges. A space $Y$ is Hausdorff iff every convergent filter on $Y$ has exactly one limit point.

Answer (score 4):

If $X$ is not Hausdorff, there are points $x,y\in X$ such that $x\ne y$, but $U\cap V\ne\varnothing$ whenever $U$ is an open nbhd of $x$ and $V$ is an open nbhd of $y$. Let $\mathscr{N}_x$ be the set of all nbhds of $x$, $\mathscr{N}_y$ the set of all nbhds of $y$, and $\mathscr{N}=\mathscr{N}_x\cup\mathscr{N}_y$. Then $U\cap V\ne\varnothing$ for all $U,V\in\mathscr{N}$, so $\mathscr{N}$ is a filter base on $X$. Let $\mathscr{U}$ be any ultrafilter on $X$ such that $\mathscr{N}\subseteq\mathscr{U}$; then every nbhd of $x$ belongs to $\mathscr{U}$, so $\mathscr{U}\to x$, and every nbhd of $y$ belongs to $\mathscr{U}$, so $\mathscr{U}\to y$. Thus, if $X$ is not Hausdorff there is an ultrafilter on $X$ that converges to two distinct points.

By the way, it isn’t true that if $X$ is Hausdorff, then every ultrafilter on $X$ has exactly one limit. What is true is that if $X$ is Hausdorff, then every ultrafilter on $X$ has **at most** one limit. If $X$ compact (but not necessarily Hausdorff), then every ultrafilter on $X$ has **at least** one limit. Thus, if $X$ is compact **and** Hausdorff, then every ultrafilter on $X$ has **exactly** one limit.